# Decomposition of the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability

We observe the input samples as $Z = X+Y$, where distribution of $Z$ could be estimated by histogram of samples and $X,Y$ are two independent random variables. One of the variable was known following exponential distribution (as $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$).

I want to get the parameter of $X$, $\lambda$, and probablity density of $Y$ with its parameters also. How to decompose the random variable $X+Y$?

Further more, what if the distribution of $X$ is unknown?

Comment: Kind of related question is addressed in this [blog](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/11/fun-with-uniform-random-numbers.html) I wrote up recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is ill-posed.  There is no unique solution if you don't specify Z.  Think about it.  Pick any Y with any distribution you choose.  X+Y will have some distribution that depends on what you chose for Y.  So if you specify Z then Y is determined but two distinct choices for Y will give two different distributions for Z.  There are infinitely many solutions to your problem.

Now given that of course your second problem is also ill-posed. Just knowing that X and Y are independent tells you almost nothing about Z.  Take X and Y normal and Z will be normal.  If X and Y are identically distributed Cauchys Z will be Cauchy.  Two independent chi-squares lead to Z being a chi-square.  So there are three solutions to problem 2 and that is only scratching the surface

In problem 1 you need to know Z's distribution to determine Y's.  In problem 2 you can't get Z without specifying the distributions of X and Y.

Comment: I can infer distribution of $Z$ by the samples as input. But it is not a typical distribution.@MichealChernick

Comment: I dont know what you mean.  You can certain fit a distribution to data if you know the family and you can construct a density nonparametrically using kernel density estimation.  But that doesnt precisely give you a mathematical formula for its distribution.

Comment: You said that if I specify $Z$ then $Y$ is determined. I can use kernel density estimation from samples instead of $Z$. But in my case parameter $\lambda$ of $X$ is unkown. So I want to estimate the $\lambda$ and pdf of $Y$. Furthermore, parameters of $Y$ are also needed to be estimated.@MichaelChernick

Comment: A kernel density estimate does not give you the distribution in a form that would enable you to estimate lambda for the exponential.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: I am not sure I agree with the first part of your reply. The distribution of $Z$ is the convolution of the distribution of $Y$ by an exponential distribution. For a given $\lambda$, there should be a single correspondence between $f_Z$ and $f_X$.

Comment: @Xi'an I agree with you: the first part of this answer is wrong (-1). It implicitly confuses *estimation* with *mathematical solution.* Given just the sample, there are many possible *estimands* for $Y$, but this does not preclude the existence of good *estimators* of $Y$, perhaps obtained through deconvolution.

Answer (score 6):

As stated, the law of $Z$ is the convolution of the law of $X$ and the law of $Y$. Finding the density of $X$ is called density deconvolution and $Y$ is generally considered as additive noise. Usually such a problem is considered by taking the fourier transforms of each variable (provided they exist) such that $f^{Ft} _Z = f^{Ft} _X \times f^{Ft} _Y$, where $f_Y ^{Ft}$ is the charateristic function of an exponential distribution in your case. Even if you were willing to give a parametric law to $X$, it is unusual that an analytic expression of $Z$ can be recovered.

Provided the Fourier transform of $Y$ never vanishes you may write $f^{Ft} _X = f^{Ft} _Z / f^{Ft} _Y$. Given a sample of realizations of $Z$ and replacing $f_Z ^{Ft}$ by the empirical characteristic function, the numerical integration back from the Fourier domain is a difficult task since the integral is generally not defined on $\mathbb{R}$. There are several methods that allow to do so if you have realizations of thes r.v. and a large sample.  and either truncate the integral over a reasonable domain or use an appropriate kernel function. In both cases you are stuck with the choice of something like a bandwidth parameter for which there are solutions.

I must say however that the joint *estimation* of $\lambda$ and $f_X$ seems very ambitious and would require to construct an optimization scheme that encompasses this parameter as well...writing this down properly might indeed turn out to be ill-posed in most cases...

Comment: It is ill-posed density deconvolution problem. Can you provide some issues related with the solution of such problem in real? btw: have you ever seen any tools can help us decompose the estimated pdf to theoretical basis distribution? @julienstirnemann

Comment: sure: you should look at the "deamer" library for R...for non-parametric density deconvolution under several hypotheses. It will yield a non parametric estimate of the density you are interested but it will not estimate $\lambda$!