# Negative value in density deconvolution

Tags: density-function, convolution

I have a set of samples from measurement. It can be expressed as random variable $Z = X + Y$. So that $Z$ is observable, but $X,Y$ is unobservable. According to prior knowledge and histogram of $Z$, I can assume that $X$ following exponential distribution with a manual selected parameter. The estimation of probability density function(pdf) of $Y$ is what I wanted. I use fft method to process this density deconvolution problem. More details can be found in this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37832/decomposition-sum-of-two-random-variables).

To solve this numerical density deconvolution problem we adopt "deconv" function supplied by pracma package in R. The results contain a block of negative value which conflict the definition of probability density. If I ignore all of those invalid value by setting them to zero and convolute it back, there would be a great mount of differences between reconvoluted value and samples. Why? How to process it?

Furthermore, if I want to get parameters of $Y$ after its pdf was estimated, perhaps a mixture of normal distribution, what should I do?

=================================================

The background is provided as complementary:
The samples are collected Round Trip Time(RTT) marked as $D_{rtt}$. It can be expressed as $D_{rtt} = D_{mech} + D_{delay}$, where $D_{mech}$ refers to time delay caused by mechanism, $D_{delay}$ is the real delay which is the main task for this analysis. $D_{mech}$ can be concluded as mixture distribution of exponential distribution and unifrom distribution. Fortunately, there is a gap between the two basic distributions in the pdf. So that I can process it separately as I modeled above.

=================================================

I add up my code for sample processing in R below.

```
delay_est = function(x, samples = 1000, thresh = 0.1){  
    library(pracma)
    lp = subset(x, value < thresh)
    d = hist(lp$value, samples)
len = length(d$density)

    fit = function(lambda){
      di = dexp(d$mids, lambda)
  dx = deconv(c(d$density, rep(0, len)), subset(di, di > 0))
      rd = dx$q[dx$q<0]
      return(sum(abs(rd)))
    }

    opt = optim(500, fit, method='Brent', lower=0, upper=10000)
    print(str(opt))  
    di = dexp(d$mids, opt$par)      
    dx = deconv(c(d$density, rep(0, len)), di)
return(list(dx$q, opt))
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is, "Maybe it's not possible."  I mean that, depending on $Z$, it might be impossible to decompose it into $X + Y$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X$ is exponential, and $Y$ is (a valid) something else.

Part of my research years ago centered on a related but more specific question: given an ordinary $Z$, is it possible to deconvolve into  $X + Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed (IID)?  It turns out, depending on $Z$, the answer is "No." Well, that's only half true: The answer is "Yes", but sometimes the distribution of $X$ (and $Y$) is negative.

I strongly suspect that a similar thing is happening to you.  You're given $Z$, yet you are specifying $X$ to be exponential and independent of $Y$.  As you have discovered, the numerical estimation of the PDF of $Y$ turns negative.  That means there is something about $Z$ which is incompatible with your other two requirements while maintaining that $Y$ is a random variable in the classical sense of the term.

Deconvolution is a difficult problem.  It's been a few years; I would need to go back and brush up on what I knew.  Also, I'm not really current on developments in recent years (if any).

But to be clear: there is nothing mathematically inconsistent or illegal about an estimated function turning negative on some parts of its domain.  There hasn't been a lot of work done concerning statistical inference in cases like that, so you're on your own when it comes time to estimate parameters, fit a model, etc.

I'd be interested to hear more about the physical problem/application that gave rise to this question: details, data, and so forth.  Who knows, maybe you've come up with something new and really cool.

Comment: It is about the decomposition of Round Trip Time(RTT) which was passively collected. The RTT is applied in TCP protocol, and could be affected by many factors. I want to decompose those effect, and build up a model with parameter to describe it. I inferred the main factor through samples and prior knowledge. Assumption that $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$ is a part of conditions, actually the model is far more complicated than that. I will provide that as complementary in the post above. @G.JayKerns

Comment: @Readon Thanks for the background; the problem sounds interesting.  I tried downloading your data (twice) from the link you gave julien, but it seems to be in some sort of binary format which I'm not sure how to read.  If you'd export your data into a text file (or similar) I'd take a look at it.  I'm not sure what you mean by "gap  between the two basic distributions in the pdf", but if it means what it sounds like it means, then there might be something else you could do.

Comment: I am very glad that you and Julien are interested in this problem. I have convert the file from R workspace file to a zipped csv file, you can download it from [here](http://www.everbox.com/f/UzjlSBHkdfCGvpY2NfLsuDOIyB). The "gap" can be found in samples' histogram which can be used to estimate its pdf. @G.JayKerns

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get negative values depending on the projection basis of functions your are considering when using fft methods in density deconvolution problems. 
However: could you give more details regarding your problem? how have you constructed your estimator? is your problem related to denoising? Does the law of $X$ belong to a knwon parametric class?
cheers

Comment: 1.The estimator was not construct manually, I use density function  provide as default in R. 2.the problem is related to density decomposition, there is no assumption about the "noise". 3. condition $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$ was mentioned above. And $Y$ as I guess (through the result with negative value), it might be mixture of two normal distribution.@julienstirnemann

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. From what I understand, your problem may be solved by nonparametric deconvolution estimators (for which R packages exist). Howevever, I'm not sure the conditions you suggest allow you to use those packages. Could you provide a minimal working example? Say a simple simulation program of what your data is and any prior conditions?

Comment: I upload samples stored in R to a server [here](http://www.everbox.com/f/ANUWs9QfHrZnNE5vgyusXgiZzC). The "value" elements in the variable blk3 is what I want to decomposed. There is no simulation program exist. @julienstirnemann

Comment: Since this appears as a data analysis problem, you must be able to present your problem in a program format using simulation, in R for example, since you have been using that software. you may add your FFT code based on that  example.

Comment: I add up my code in above post. I don't know whether it is what you mean.@julienstirnemann

Comment: Your problem is still not in proper statistical language. You have 3 random variables. Some are observable, some are not. You have a sample of observations for one or 2 variables. For some variables, assumptions may arise from background knowledge which should be clearly presented. I guess your  objective is to deconvolve the law of an unobserved r.v. when only a convolution of the variable of interest and some other r.v. is observed. Each of these points must be made very clear for your problem to be tractable by others nonfamiliar with your specific problem.

Comment: Whenever this is difficult to express a minimal working example helps, but it should actually reproduce your problem using standard programming and basic skills.

Comment: I edit the first block of above post. The objective is to deconvolve the law of an unobserved r.v. when only a convolution of the variable of interest and some other r.v. is also unobserved, but can give a reasonable assumption on its distribution. @juliens