# Product of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I have a sample of about 1000 values​​. These data are obtained from the product of two independent random variables $\xi \ast \psi $. The first random variable has a uniform distribution $\xi \sim U(0,1)$. The distribution of the second random variable is not known. How can I estimate the distribution of the second ($ \psi $) random variable?

Comment: This is a version of what is called a deconvolution problem: if you move to the log of the product, you get the estimated distribution of the sum when you know the distribution of one of the terms. Check on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution).

Comment: See also this [related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/37832/7224) on crossvalidated: once you apply the log transform, the problem is equivalent.

Comment: To expand on Xi'an's answer, if you take $-\log \xi \psi$ you get the convolution of a known exponential r.v. and something of the form $-\log \psi$, so after the transformation you are exactly in the situation he linked to. After you estimate the distribution of $-\log \psi$ you can then transform that into an estimate for the distribution of $\psi$

Comment: @Xi'an: Nice links. I sure hope that $\psi \geq 0$ almost surely...though we can recover from a seemingly fatal violation of this condition by decomposing as $\psi = \psi_{+} - \psi_{-}$ and considering the pieces separately.

Comment: Here is a [reference](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aos/1176348248) on nonparametric deconvolution.

Comment: @cardinal I'm curious about how the estimation problem is handled when some of the data might be negative. How is the decomposition determined? (The intuitive method of assigning data less than $1$ to one component and data greater than $1$ to another looks suboptimal to me because the convolution with the exponential will tend to turn values coming from the $\psi_{-}$ component into relatively large positive observations.) It looks rather like the estimator *simultaneously* has to handle the identification of the mixture and the deconvolution--and that appears tricky to do.

Comment: @whuber: Apologies in advance for only having given your comment a cursory reading. I was a little unsure of what you're driving at. To (slightly) clarify my suggestion: If $Z = \xi \psi$, decompose as $Z := Z_{+} - Z_{-}$ where $Z_{+} = \xi \psi_{+}$ and $Z_{-} = \xi \psi_{-}$. Note that $\psi_{+} \geq 0$ iff $Z_{+} \geq 0$, so in particular, the number of negative samples is a sufficient statistic for $\mathbb P(Z < 0)$. Now apply deconvolution to $Z_{+}$ and $Z_{-}$ separately. I don't see how one estimate can contaminate the other since the original supports (...)

Comment: (...) are disjoint and will be respected once we transform back via $\exp$. The mixture weight is obtained from the proportion of negative samples. I fear I must have misunderstood your comment or am overlooking something. I admit this comment and the previous were almost completely off-the-cuff. Hopefully they have not introduced too much noise.

Comment: @Cardinal thanks for the explanation. No, not noise: because I was thinking in terms of logarithms, I had simply forgotten that $\xi$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 4):

We have, Assuming $\psi$ has support on the positive real line,
$$\xi \,\psi = X$$ Where $X \sim F_n$ and $F_n$ is the empirical distribution of the data.
Taking the log of this equation we get,

$$ Log(\xi) + Log(\psi) = Log(X) $$

Thus by Levy's continuity theorem, and independance of $\xi$ and$\psi$
taking the charactersitic functions:

$$ \Psi_{Log(\xi)}(t)\Psi_{Log(\psi)}(t) = \Psi_{Log(X)}$$

Now, $ \xi\sim Unif[0,1]$$, therefore $$-Log(\xi) \sim Exp(1) $
Thus,
$$\Psi_{Log(\xi)}(-t)= \left(1 + it\right)^{-1}\,$$

Given that $\Psi_{ln(X)} =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{1000}\exp(itX_k) ,$
With $ X_1 ... X_{1000}$ The random sample of $\ln(X)$.

We can now specify completly the distribution of $Log(\psi)$ through its characteristic function:

$$ \left(1 + it\right)^{-1}\,\Psi_{Log(\psi)}(t) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{1000}\exp(itX_k)$$

If we assume  that the moment generating functions of $\ln(\psi)$ exist and that $t<1$ we can write the above equation in term of moment generating functions:

$$ M_{Log(\psi)}(t) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{1000}\exp(-t\,X_k)\,\left(1 - t\right)\,$$

It is enough then to invert the Moment generating function to get the distribution of $ln(\phi)$ and thus that of $\phi$

Comment: can you explain this with an example in R?

Comment: Of course. I ll try to post it tomorrow.